# meaning of so much as

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence, I want to know if I've understand the correct meaning or not:

> This version holds that the wave function does not **so much** describe the state of the physical system **as** the state of our *knowledge* of the system.

Can we say that it means the wave function describes the state of our *knowledge*  of the system **more than** it describes the state of the physical system  ?

It is worth noting that in the Cambridge Dictionary, we read:

**not so much sth as sth**
​
If you say that something is not so much one thing as something else, you mean it is more the second thing:
They're not so much lovers as friends.
I don't feel angry so much as sad.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial thoughts seem correct. According to "this version" the wave function does more to describe the 'state of our knowledge' than the 'state of the physical system'.

I have heard this structure used most often to clarify when one might have been led to believe one thing, but something else is, in fact, more likely to be true. As in this variation on an example from Google:

"He kept saying that his novel was unfinished. I believe, however, that it was not so much unfinished as it was unfinishable."

Answer (score 0):

"Not so much something as something" works when the two items being compared are different in degree in some way. So friendship and love are forms of personal relationship that differ in degree of closeness. The @Toby A example refers differing degrees of finishability.

But when the difference is one of kind, the expression does not work well. You could not really say, "Not so much black as white".

Where the difference is of kind, a better choice could be "Not something but rather something."

Now, the specific example you give looks very much as if it is referring to an alternative to the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics that is based on Bayesian concepts. If that is so, then it is arguable that there is such a fundamental difference between the two concepts that "Not...but rather..." would be better than "Not so much...as..."